24" 2k vs 27" 2k monitor for Mac Book Pro 13 inch M1chip (2020) - Better text clarity and a lot of reading!
I am new to Mac and need help buying a suitable monitor.I am a technical writer and need to read/write a lot of text. Screen size (multiple tabs) and text clarity (clearer the better) are my priority. My MacBook Pro has 1440×990 default display size.
I was thinking of buying BenQ Gw2790Qt which is 27" 2K monitor. Not sure about text clarity (which is very important to me) but it has all the other features I need (I do code) + Eyecare.
But, when I went to local store and connected my MacBook (13-inch, M1 chip 2020) to a 2K Asus TOF monitor and BenQ Mobius, to check if 2K works for my mac (office laptop), it was so pixelated and grey that it gave me headache and that weird blurry feeling in the eye within minutes. (Note: for 2K Asus TUF the Mac display output was something around 940-1080 and for BenQ Mobius (which was kinda better) 1080). They didn't have the BenQ Gw2790Qt on display, I will have to pre-book it and it's not refundable.
Note: My Galaxy Tab S7+ gave better output for almost both the displays (BenQ Mobius > Asus TUF)
Now, I am confused. Will 24" 2K monitor be a better option for my MacBook Pro?
Again text clarity, eyecare, Type-C connectivity with adjustable stand is my priority. Can anyone suggest a monitor model or the size and resolution I should go with? (I am from India)
I do watch videos and do light (minimal) editing.
I have also read type c connection is better than hdmi or dp connection. My MacBook has only 2 type c ports.
Honestly, I like my Galaxy S7+ more than this MacBook Pro M1 2020.
